# How to use XSL to count element value occurrences?

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I am trying to count the occurrences of different node values with xsl.  Here's an xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<data>
<hit><date>2021-03-23</date><time>04:13:01 pm</time><type>viewed</type><info>twitter</info></hit>
<hit><date>2021-03-23</date><time>05:01:49 pm</time><type>conversion</type><info>instagram</info></hit>
<hit><date>2021-04-06</date><time>08:03:09 am</time><type>viewed</type><info>youtube</info></hit>
<hit><date>2021-04-07</date><time>07:27:41 pm</time><type>viewed</type><info>youtube</info></hit>
<hit><date>2021-04-07</date><time>10:32:45 pm</time><type>viewed</type><info>youtube</info></hit>
</data>
```

I would like an output along the lines of 2021-03-23 = 2, 2021-04-06 = 1, 2021-04-07 = 2, counting occurrences of values in data/hit/date.

Also, differentiating by type would be nice too.  For example: 2021-03-23 = 2 hits, 1 viewed, and 1 conversion.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a grouping issue. You don't specify which version of XSLT you're using and you didn't post an example of what you've tried.

Grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0+ using xsl:for-each-group. Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is done using the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

I'll go with the worst case scenario and assume XSLT 1.0. Take a look at the link above to learn about Muenchian Grouping so my example makes sense.

What I would do is create a key to group all `hit` elements by their `date` children.
I'd create another key to group `hit` elements by a combination of `date` and `type` elements.

You can then use these keys to do the grouping and counting...

**XML Input**

```xml
<data>
    <hit><date>2021-03-23</date><time>04:13:01 pm</time><type>viewed</type><info>twitter</info></hit>
    <hit><date>2021-03-23</date><time>05:01:49 pm</time><type>conversion</type><info>instagram</info></hit>
    <hit><date>2021-04-06</date><time>08:03:09 am</time><type>viewed</type><info>youtube</info></hit>
    <hit><date>2021-04-07</date><time>07:27:41 pm</time><type>viewed</type><info>youtube</info></hit>
    <hit><date>2021-04-07</date><time>10:32:45 pm</time><type>viewed</type><info>youtube</info></hit>
</data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="hit-by-date" match="hit" use="date"/>
    <xsl:key name="hit-by-date-type" match="hit" use="concat(date,'~',type)"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="hit[count(.|key('hit-by-date',date)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(date,' = ',count(key('hit-by-date',date)),' hits')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('hit-by-date',date)[count(.|key('hit-by-date-type',concat(date,'~',type))[1])=1]">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(', ', count(key('hit-by-date-type',concat(date,'~',type))),' ',type)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
2021-03-23 = 2 hits, 1 viewed, 1 conversion
2021-04-06 = 1 hits, 1 viewed
2021-04-07 = 2 hits, 2 viewed
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtEu

Comment: Thank you for that answer and explanation.  Noted about not including the version.  I was using version 1.0.  It had been some time since I worked with xsl and had a random, quick need to use it.